# Python: XGboost on windows doesn't work (openmp runtime is not installed (vcomp140.dll or libgomp-1.dll)

Tags: python, boost

I had the above listed problem happen to me, there are loads of answers for Linux and Mac around, but I didn't find an answer that would help me on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Installing MinGW fixed it. Just followed the installation instructions and now it works.

https://nuwen.net/mingw.html